# Data structure to represent a shopping cart

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures, linked-list

What would be the correct data structure to use to represent a shopping cart contents?

1. Linked list
2. Array
3. Array List
4. Something else

Im not thinking in terms of what is the most convenient i.e. just use an array, but more in terms of what is most correct.

This would be a very standard idea of a shopping cart which would contain the following:

1. Basic Meta data about the cart such as subtotal etc
2. Collection of cart items each containing properties for cart information such as qty and price and a product property which contains access to the underlying product

Also the following is important:

1. Items should be able to be added and removed
2. The cart should be able to be emptied in a single action
3. Certain parts of the meta data should be updated when items are added/removed such as subtotal, qty etc.

Comment: In order to answer that you should supply a list of relevant features which should be supported by your cart, the product structure etc. The there'll be pro's and cons and you'll have to decide what do you want according to the trade off. This question is too broad...

Comment: I have updated with some specific considerations

Answer (score 3):

- Array: I wouldn't really do this because you have to know how many items will go in the shopping cart before hand and this will force you to resize/re-initialize the array many times.
- LinkedList *(which don't use Array in its implementation)*: I mostly would go with this especially that it fits with the rest of the requirements you mentioned.
- Hashed Collection: It could be used but not very suitable for this situation given the fact that fast access to the contents of the basket by a certain key element is not required.

Bottom of the line, i would simply model the shopping cart as most developers would an order with a list of order items, so i would have a shopping cart class with a getter for the total number of items, total price, etc and model the cotents using a linked list.

Of course you might want to consider distribution if it is a factor but for the most situations the above should be more than enough.

Comment: I agree with the above poster. Use a linked list since they can be of variable length. Deleting a specific item is at worst O(n) and inserting is O(1). Clearing the entire cart is theta(n). 

The linked list object could contain an enum ITEM or something, that you can check to see its associated cost when inserting (or deleting) and then modify the subtotal and quantity fields of the cart object containing the linked list.

Comment: Can stack be used instead of linked list?

Comment: My future self answering this right now which I hope is wiser would try to approach this a bit differently. Choosing the correct data structure means you have to ask yourself what kind of operations you intend to run mostly on it.
In this case: adding, removing, re-ordering or clearing. Also a shopping car will most likely not contain more than a hundred items or so. So an array doesn't really sound too bad for this.

Comment: Of course, if your application becomes so popular you would be wasting some space with array so a trade-off like always need to be considered here.

Comment: Let's check how does that fit with Stack:
- Adding is easy
- Removing is not, what if you want to remove something from the middle of the cart, then you would have to pop items and push them back
- Re-ordering is costly
So IMHO it doesn't fit the need

Answer (score 0):

Basic CPP Program for shopping cart

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Item {
    string name;
    int quantity;
    int price;
};

class ShoppingCart {
private:
    vector<Item> item;
    int total_price;
public:
    ShoppingCart();
    void addItem(string name, int quantity, int price);
    void removeItem(string name, int quantity);
    int getTotal();
};

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart() {
    cout << "Creating a new shopping cart" << endl;
    total_price = 0;
}

void ShoppingCart::addItem(string name, int quantity, int price) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
        if (item[i].name == name) {
            item[i].quantity += quantity;
            return;
        }
    }

    Item temp;
    temp.name = name;
    temp.quantity = quantity;
    temp.price = price;
    item.push_back(temp);
}

void ShoppingCart::removeItem(string name, int quantity) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
        if (item[i].name == name) {
            if (item[i].quantity >= quantity) {
                item[i].quantity -= quantity;
                return;
            }
            cout << "Not enough items present in the cart to be removed" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "This item is not present in the cart" << endl;
}

int ShoppingCart::getTotal() {
    total_price = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
        total_price += item[i].quantity * item[i].price;
    }
    return total_price;
}

int main() {
    ShoppingCart cart;
    cart.addItem("Maggi", 10, 5);
    cart.addItem("Biryani", 2, 15);
    cart.addItem("Ketchup", 1, 5);
    cout << "Total cost: " << cart.getTotal() << endl;
    cart.addItem("Football", 2, 15);
    cart.removeItem("Maggi", 4);
    cart.removeItem("Ketchup", 2);
    cout << cart.getTotal() << endl;
    cart.addItem("Candy", 15, 2);
    cart.removeItem("Bat", 1);
    cout << "Total cost: " << cart.getTotal() << endl;
}
```